# How to make a vertical slider?

Tags: livecode

I need a vertical slider similar the standard slider. Is there a way to modify the existing one or do I need to make a new one?

The standard slider would work for me. I just need it to work vertically.

Perhaps I should better clarify my issue with the standard slider.
Yes, I can drag the size of the slider and it will be vertical. The problem is that when you select the value of the slider to show the text gets buried in the low side of the slider when you slide it down all the way. It essentially gets cut off and only shows the top half of the slider value character. I find no way to correct this by moving the shown text up a little so it all shows. I see no way to change text vertical or offset position in the properties setting.
The text settings only allow you to change the text format to right, center and left justify. There is no setting that can move the text up to prevent it from being cut off when the slider is all the way to the lower or down position.
The value text shows ok on the top of the slider. The problem is on the bottom side when you set the slider to be vertical.
It looks like the the show value setting does not place the value on the top layer of the slider and it gets hidden behind something else in the slider object.
LC9, Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm understanding your question. If you just resize the horizontal slider control so that the width is narrower than the height, the orientation of the slider control will automatically change to vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a bug in this version of LC. At least in Win which is where I am testing.
Putting the scrollbar vertically cuts the value when it reaches the bottom.
But I found a solution so that it does not cut. Play around with the properties of the font. Such as size and family. In my case it worked fine by lowering the font size by one pixel.
[image]
Default: Segoe UI font, size 12
I just set the size to 11 and it doesn't cut anymore.

Comment: The small font works but my application is on a 27 inch display so the smaller font does not work for me. Do you think sending this to bugzilla would get it fixed?

Comment: Send it in, maybe it's something they'll fix soon. But while you can use a field to put the value of the scroll bar. While they fix this bug

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I do not see this issue on a Mac. A vertical slider works as advertised. Font size makes no difference.

Are you saying that in the horizontal mode, you do not see this, but when changed to vertical, you do?

Comment: Yup... I am on Windows.. Works OK on horizontal.. problem is only on vertical

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a scrollbar and a text field.
Set the scrollbar's showValue property to false and copy the following script to your scrollbar. Note that your field must be called "scroll value".

```
on scrollbarDrag pNewPosition
   local tLoc
   lock screen
   
   # The Current Loc of Field
   put the loc of field "scroll value" into tLoc
   
   # New Position of scrollbar
   put pNewPosition into field "scroll value"
   
   # New Loc of Field
   put the mouseV into the item 2 of tLoc
   set the loc of field "scroll value" to tLoc
   set the left of field "scroll value" to the right of me

   unlock screen
end scrollbarDrag
```